# Handlebars print a table with dynamic array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have an array of objects:

```js
const arr =
[
   {
    user: 'b@b.com',
    name: 'b',
    surname: 'b',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'YES',
    '11_11_2022': 'YES'
  },
   {
    user: 'c@c.com',
    name: 'c',
    surname: 'c',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'NO',
    '11_11_2022': 'NO'
  }
]
```

All the dates and the values are dynamic.

My problem is, i don't know how to access the dates without knowing the name of the index. My code is:

```html
{{#each arr}}
    <p> USER {{this.user}}  </p>      Works
    <p> Name {{this.name}}  </p>      Works
    <p> USER {{this.surname}}  </p>   Works
    <p> Date1 {{??????}}  </p>        ?????
{{/each}}
```

My view is something like this:

```html
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>

        <th>USER</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SURNAME</th>

        {{#Date}} <th> {{moment Date format="DD/MM/YYYY"}} </th> {{/Date}}

    </tr>

    {{#each arr}}
    <tr>

        <th>{{user}}</th>
        <th>{{name}}</th>
        <th>{{surname}} </th>

        maybe another each here
        <th>{{???????}}</th>
        close that each

    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

I want to print a table like this one:

```
  | USER    | NAME | Surname | date 1 | date 2 | date 3 |
  | b@b.com |  b   |    b    |  YES   |   YES  |  YES   |
  | c@c.com |  c   |    c    |  YES   |   NO   |  NO    |
```

Comment: Are the keys always the same for all object's array?

Comment: no, i can have more dates or less. that is why the Dates are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have different keys in some objects

```js
const arr = [
  {
    user: 'b@b.com',
    name: 'b',
    surname: 'b',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'YES',
    '11_11_2022': 'YES'
  },
  {
    user: 'c@c.com',
    name: 'c',
    surname: 'c',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'NO',
    '11_11_2022': 'NO',
    '11_11_2023': 'NO'
  }
]

const keys = [...new Set(arr.flatMap((content) => Object.keys(content)))]

console.log(keys)
```

I can't test but does something like this works ?

```js
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    {{#each keys as | key |}}
      <th>{{key}}</th>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{#each arr as | user |}}
  <tr>
    {{#each ../keys as | key |}}
     <th>{{lookup user key}}</th>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

My result with previous arr and keys

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <th>user</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>surname</th>
      <th>29_07_2022</th>
      <th>01_08_2022</th>
      <th>11_11_2022</th>
      <th>11_11_2023</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>b@b.com</th>
     <th>b</th>
     <th>b</th>
     <th>YES</th>
     <th>YES</th>
     <th>YES</th>
     <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>c@c.com</th>
     <th>c</th>
     <th>c</th>
     <th>YES</th>
     <th>NO</th>
     <th>NO</th>
     <th>NO</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that gave me only the names [
  'user',
  'name',
  'surname',
  '29_07_2022',
  '01_08_2022',
  '11_11_2022'
]

Comment: When I run the snippet, I have [
  "user",
  "name",
  "surname",
  "29_07_2022",
  "01_08_2022",
  "11_11_2022",
  "11_11_2023"
] Did you test the good part, I remove the first option where objects were the same

Comment: yes, but i need the handlebars call, i can call user, name and surname but how do i call the dates wich i don't know the names?
i thought calling them with the index [User 0, name 1, surname 2, Date 1 3, etc]

Comment: I just add a part for handlebars at the end

Comment: no, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, first time with handlebars, is this ok?

Comment: YES!!!!!! that work like a charm. thanks! only i need to change the _ for the /   :)

Comment: Easy way is to create a copy of keys like `const titleKeys = keys.map((key) => key.replace('_', '/'))` and use it here `{{#each keys as | key |}}` instead of `keys`

Comment: weird it only replaces one, not both, it  shows like this 11/11_2023

Comment: replaceAll then, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As I see for your comment `maybe another each here` the objects can have different times.

In that case, you must handle the dates in another array to iterate them and consult inside if the object has that value equal to `YES`.

Handlebars don't have a method to compare values, so you will need to change your object values to `true` or `false`. Another solution is create a `Helper` as is in the next example:

```js
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const fs = require("fs");

const arr = [
    {
    user: 'b@b.com',
    name: 'b',
    surname: 'b',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'YES',
    '11_11_2022': 'YES'
    },
    {
    user: 'c@c.com',
    name: 'c',
    surname: 'c',
    '29_07_2022': 'YES',
    '01_08_2022': 'NO',
    '11_11_2022': 'NO'
    },
    {
        user: 'd@d.com',
        name: 'd',
        surname: 'd',
        '11_11_3000': 'YES'
    }
];

// Handle your dates keys
const dateHeaders = new Set();
// const data = [];
for (const value of arr) {
    // Get only dates of the object
    const dates = new Set(Object.keys(value));
    dates.delete("user");
    dates.delete("name");
    dates.delete("surname");

    // Concat dates
    for (const date of dates) {
        dateHeaders.add(date)
    }
}

// Create an equal condition to use it
// You can ignore it if change the value 'YES' & 'NO' to true & false
handlebars.registerHelper('equal', function (value, value2) {
    return value === value2 ? true : false;
});

// Execute handlebars sending the array and the dateHeaders
const template = handlebars.compile(fs.readFileSync("./template.html", "utf8"));
fs.writeFileSync("./output.html", template({
    arr,
    dateHeaders,
}));
```

**template.html**

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>USER</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SURNAME</th>
        {{#each dateHeaders}}
        <th>{{this}}</th>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{#each arr}}
    <tr>
        <th>{{user}}</th>
        <th>{{name}}</th>
        <th>{{surname}}</th>
        {{#each ../dateHeaders}}
        {{#if (equal (lookup ../this this) "YES")}}
        <th>YES</th>
        {{else}}
        <th>NO</th>
        {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

**output.html**

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>USER</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SURNAME</th>
        <th>29_07_2022</th>
        <th>01_08_2022</th>
        <th>11_11_2022</th>
        <th>11_11_3000</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>b@b.com</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>YES</th>
        <th>YES</th>
        <th>YES</th>
        <th>NO</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>c@c.com</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>YES</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>d@d.com</th>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>YES</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***NOTE:** If you want the dates in an specific order (actually is FIFO) you must convert dateHeaders to an `Array` and apply a `sort`.*